# hiding angular-modal-gallery and trigger using service only

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to hide the clickable preview icons on an `angular-modal-gallery` running on an angular 5 SPA component. As the modal is going to be triggered through a bootstrap button.

I have the following in my component.html;

```
<ks-modal-gallery [id]="1" [modalImages]="images"></ks-modal-gallery>
```

From inspecting I can see that it generates a div with the class `plain-container`. I have tried overriding this class in the component.css;

```
.plain-container {
     display:none !important; }
```

However, this isn't been applied (I assume because of the point of html is being generated).

Can anyone help find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the CSS globally in your style.css file. It will surely work.

Comment: Consider elaborating a little on how and why this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add boolean isGalleryOpen = false, and set attr hidden with it.

```
isGalleryOpen = false;
```

open method

```
openModalViaService(id: number | undefined, index: number) {
this.isGalleryOpen = true;
this.galleryService.openGallery(id, index);
}
```

In HTML turn boolean false on close event.

```
<ks-modal-gallery [attr.hidden]="isGalleryOpen === true ? null : 'true'" 
(close)="isGalleryOpen=false;" [id]="1" [modalImages]="images"></ks-modal-gallery>
```